# execvp(), can't return to command line directly

Tags: c++, operating-system, exec, fork

I'm playing with execvp(), and found a interesting thing, here is the code first of all.
using namespace std;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

    char *argv[3];
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0){
    argv[0] = "ls";
    argv[1] = "-l";
    argv[2] = NULL;
    execvp("ls", argv);
    }

}
```

This is a simple fork + execvp problem, but I found that after "ls" was executed successfully, **I will have to hit Enter to come back to command line (shell)**.

Anyone know how do I make it so that after execvp("ls") I can go back to shell without hit my "Enter"?

Comment: I'll wager you don't actually have to hit Enter. Try just entering a command (`echo hello`, for example) and *then* hit enter.

Comment: I question whether that's true. Try something like executing your program and *immediately* typing another command (like `echo hello`) and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main program exits before the `ls` completes. By the time `ls` completes, its output has obscured the shell prompt.

You can solve this with either of these:

- Add `else wait(0);` after the `if`'s closing brace.
- Delete the call to `fork()`.